# Converting Images to higher Resolution in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, image, api, dart, image-processing

If we upload lower resolution images from local storage on our app and we want to convert those to higher resolution images in flutter dart. How can we do that?? Is it possible?? Are there any APIs available that can convert lower resolution images to higher resolution??

Comment: you can do that but you can't magically create any image detail that isn't already there. you're just inflating the image.

Comment: You can use an ai image upscaling API like this one: https://icons8.de/upscaler

Comment: @Colin can you please recommend any free alternative of above mentioned API?

Comment: I can't recommend one but I've found this one with a Google search. https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/torch-srgan